# K2 Blackpearl - populating SmartObject attributes

Tags: k2

I'm very new to learning how to use K2 Blackpearl and am trying to understand how to effectively use SmartObjects.

Basically I have a list of questions I want to ask a user so currently I've created a smartObject with 2 attributes (Question, Answer). I have a list of all the questions I want to ask stored in a SQL server db.

Is it possible to auto-create either an InfoPath form or as ASP.NET page (At this stage I'm not too bothered which one I use - just want to see something working so please feel free to recommend which one is easiest) which will get the questions from the database and auto-create the 'fields' which the user will need to place an answer to the question... Then save this back to the smart object?

Thanks in advance for any help, much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I see this question is very old and the suggestion of using InfoPath was probably good back then. For the record, as of today, InfoPath is no longer the recommended option.

Today, using SmartForms, I would create one SmartObject (smo) for your question/answer table (assuming there is a single answer per question, one table it enough). In your table, don´t forget colums to store whether the question is answered or not, by whom and when.

I would then suggest making 2 views: one list view to see all the questions and one item view mainly to answer a question.

When the user clicks on a question in the list view, you load it into the item view. The user can type/select and answer in the item view and click a button to 'send the answer' which effectively calls the update method of the smo.

This is s standard pattern, similar to listing updating users or pretty much any data in your DB. You just need to think about your data model to ensure you won´t stuck later on.

Comment: Indeed InfoPath should no longer be considered as an easiest or in any way preferable solution. For scenario described SmartForms is best option where you just do right click on existing SmartObject and use auto-generated views (List, Item etc.) and from that you can see how to customize them a bit more later if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

InfoPath is easiest to go, there's no real development, just clicking.

You can use a smartObject on the SQL database (using the Dynamic SQL Service Broker) to get the questions and load them in the InfoPath form. On the submit of the form, you can push the questions and answers to the SmartObject.

I would suggest making the 'answer' smartobject also based on a sql table, so you're data is nicely placed together.